# Selecting other qualities in a hls live streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, http-live-streaming

I am trying to develop an ios application which permits to visualize a streaming using the protocol hls. As hls is by default adaptive, I can only select the most suitable quality for my connection. I cannot access other qualities from my developed ios application. Is there a way to access the four streams from an m3u8 link? I am using objective c as language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m3u8 is a text based file format so you can just open it and parse the sources it is describing.